# How can I version-control my SQL Server database files with Git?

Tags: sql-server, git, version-control

OK, I'm warming up to Git and DropBox for version control. I'm creating DNN sites and I'm in the process of using Git/DropBox.

I would also like to use Git on the SQL Server backing database.

Is there some sort of best practice that could be employed here?
I'm currently getting an access denied error when I attempt to create a repository in the SQL Server DATA directory.

Comment: I wouldnt backup data directory since it is not version agnostic, and not a good idea for distributed development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have permissions to make a .git folder in there. I would use the sql server tools to create the backup files elsewhere. I would then back those up. You should have no problem putting those in a git repo.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I set my database file location to a custom directory, then stopped the database service and added read/full rights for all users in the system to the file. After that, git had no problem adding the file to version control.